# Задание связанное с CharArray C#

Tags: c#, массивы, строки, char

Помогите сделать задание, очень нужно.
Вот условие:
***Задан текст,  состоящий из произвольной последовательности буквенных символов. Упорядочить их в алфавитном порядке, при этом если символ встречается четное количество раз(но не 0), то остается 1 копия. Если нечетное(более 3х), то  2 копии.*** 
Я смог сделать в алфавитном порядке(код ниже), но с копиями у меня проблема, пробовал по разному, в итоге не смог реализовать.
Сам код с сортировкой по алфавиту:

```
 char[] text3;
 text3 = "sdersdsdsdfghjklaosd".ToCharArray();
        char[] array = text3.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
        foreach (char ch in array)
            Console.Write(char.ToLower(ch));
        Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: На выходе какой результат должен быть?

Comment: `var result = text.OrderBy(x => x).GroupBy(x => x).SelectMany(x => (x.Count() % 2) == 0 ? x.Take(1) : x.Take(2));` -> `addefghjklorss`.

Comment: Да, результат должен быть таким "addefghjklorss", но почему не работает ваша linq?

Comment: Я от куда знаю что у вас там не работает. У меня лично все [идеально](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g9F77p) :-)

Comment: Нашел ошибку, спасибо огромное)